# C# Pluginsystem security

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, security

I've successfully implemented a Pluginsystem in my WPF-Application:

Every Plugin has its own *.dll to be loaded and instantiated at the start of my App.

Are there any security issues caused by the fact that someone could develop a plugin and write everything in the constructor she/he wants to?

If so, how could I prevent this?

Comment: You could choose to only load DLL files which have been cryptographically signed only by yourself and trusted publishers.

Comment: Common sense tells you that somebody apart from the original developer being able to throw some new code in the constructor is a problem...

Comment: @Dai Not a bad idea, but that opens up the next question... How do you go about vetting who is and is not trusted to publish?

Comment: @JayGould With "Constructor" I ment the Constructor of the developed Plugin

Comment: @Dai good idea, thanks. Situation: A developer ask me if he can develop a plugin and if I give him a Special key or something similiar that he will paste in his plugin. Before loading the plugin I could then check the Key and if its valid, it will be loaded. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think what you are looking for is AppDomain, here you can create an isolated sandbox and grant permissions for the running code. For example a specific folder for reading/writing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I got it right, my whole Application is the sandbox and I have to execute the untrusted Code like before but with permissions?

Comment: No, you create a sandbox (AppDomain) for your dlls to load in. One for all, one for each or some other setup, depending on your need and architecture. Your main application runs as usual.

Comment: @J R I found the perfect example: https://github.com/UAV/PlugInLoader only have to figure out how to add permissions and restrictions.

Comment: @F.Baum Great! Permissions is sent to one of AppDoman.CreateDomain() overloads. That implementation you found does not seem to use that tho, but should not be too hard to add!

Comment: @J R Thanks! Got this little snippet from MSDN: public static AppDomain CreateDomain(
 string friendlyName,
 Evidence securityInfo,
 AppDomainSetup info,
 PermissionSet grantSet,
 params StrongName[] fullTrustAssemblies
) But what does the StrongName[] mean?

Comment: @F.Baum "An array of strong names representing assemblies to be considered fully trusted in the new application domain.". So if you for example have a default plugin you developed yourself that does more then the permissions granted to the rest of the plugins allow you add that one.